# How to create a subdirectory in a child-theme via functions.php from the Theme editor without FTP acces?

Tags: php

I would like to override a file from a WC-vendor plugin with a file I place in the child theme, but I do not have access to the server via FTP or the Terminal. So I can not just create and upload folders easy. My approach is to use functions.php file from the child theme in the Theme Editor:

I can create a new file

```
// Create a new file in a subfolder
add_action('after_setup_theme', function() {
    $file = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/settings.php';
    touch($file);
});
```

but when I use a path with subfolders it does not create the file

```
// Create a new file in a subfolder
add_action('after_setup_theme', function() {
    $file = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/wc-vendors/dashboard/settings/settings.php';
    touch($file);
});
```

On my local machine it spits out following error message

> file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/panfruta/wp-content/themes/astra-child/functions.php on line 31

I tried to create folder with

`mkdir($file, 0777);`

without success.

Is there a workaround to create the desired folder structure?

Comment: **This plan will not work as that's not how child themes work.** Child themes let you override templates, not arbitrary PHP files. Even then, if you have access to edit those files there's no reason to modify the theme folder programatically, and if you make even a single mistake you could cripple the site and eliminate your only access route. This is an extreme risk, bad practice plan. If you can't use hooks then you need to speak to the theme/plugin vendor

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your answer I totally get that this is not best practice. Do you know a different way to create a folder structure in a child theme?

Comment: Merlin, you can't override that file by putting a copy with changes in a child theme, you can only do that with templates loaded by `get_template_part`. It's not a case of good or bad practice, what you're trying to do will never work, wether you create the folder in code, or via FTP. So even if you get the folder and file created, it will make no difference. That's why I left a comment ( not an answer ). That is not how child themes work.

Comment: I understand what you wanted to explain with your answer about what child themes are for. Sorry for the lack of communication that it is about about overriding template files. The method of overriding via a child theme is what is suggested in the description of the settings.php file. I used a file manager plugin to create the desired folder structure and it works fine. I was just curious if there is a way to run a code snippet once and delete it afterwards.